# Why the the following limit is $1$? (This result is given by Maple.)

Tags: limits

Why the the following limit is $1$? (This result is given by Maple.)
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\,\frac{\ln(Ax+Bx^b)}{\ln(x)},$$ where $A>0,B>0,0<b<1$ are contants.

Comment: Have you tried with the L'Hôpital Rule?

Comment: The limit is not $1$ unless $b=1$. I'm curious about what Maple is doing.

Comment: But, when you apply L'Hopilal you arrive to
$$
\frac{Ax+Bbx^{b}}{Ax+Bx^{b}}.
$$
Since $b<1$, the leading term both in the numerator and denominator is $Ax$. Since is the same in both parts, the limit is 1

Comment: Precisely because $b<1$, the leading term is $x^b$.

Comment: @LaloVelasco, thank you for your answer! But once again applying the L'Hopilal rule to the $\frac{Ax+Bbx^b}{Ax+Bx^b}$, the result will be $b$. Will you please help me to explain this result?

Comment: @Martin Argerami, Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have understood my mistake: $x^{b}$ is "larger" than $x$ as $x\rightarrow 0$. Thanks @MartinArgerami!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $1-b>0$, 
$$
\frac{\log(Ax+Bx^b)}{\log x}=\frac{\log(x^b(Ax^{1-b}+B))}{\log x}
=\frac{b\log x+\log(Ax^{1-b}+B)}{\log x}
=b+\frac{\log(Ax^{1-b}+B)}{\log x}
$$
and then
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\log(Ax+Bx^b)}{\log x}=b.
$$

The second term goes to zero because the numerator converges to $\log B$.